# rails: Paginate posts for current forum_thread_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I'm trying to paginate my posts under it's forum_thread_id.
When I paginate @forum_posts I'm getting all the posts and not the ones specific to the thread id that I'm in.

I'm using will_paginate for pagination.

It's probably any easy fix that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Routes: http://paste.ofcode.org/5UM3BALunD6gCD2gvsxmSz

Comment: Do not use paste.ofcode.org in your post, as the links expire after a week. Add the code directly into the question instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter the query with the ForumThread id, try something like this (modify the code accordingly)

```
def show
    @forum_post = ForumPost.new
    @forum_posts = ForumPost.where(forum_thread_id: @forum_thread.id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
def show
   @forum_post = ForumPost.new
   @forum_posts = ForumThread.find(params[:id])
   @forum_posts = ForumPost.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
end
```

You're paginating the equivalent of `ForumPost.all`, which means you're going to get back all the posts, regardless of which `thread` they're a part of.

You need:

```
def show
  @forum_post = ForumPost.new

  @forum_thread = ForumThread.find params[:id]
  @forum_posts  = @forum_thread.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
end
```

This is assuming you have the following setup:

```
#app/models/forum_thread.rb
class ForumThread < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :forum_posts
end

#app/models/forum_post.rb
class ForumPost < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :forum_thread
end
```

---

As an aside (this is advanced), you'd be much better putting your `thread` and `post` models into a `Forum` module:

```
#app/models/forum.rb
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :threads, class_name: "Forum::Thread"
end

#app/models/forum/thread.rb
class Forum::Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :forum
   has_many :posts, class_name: "Forum::Post"
end

#app/models/forum/post.rb
class Forum::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :thread, class_name: "Forum::Thread"
end
```

This would allow you to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope path: ":forum_id", as: "forum" do
   resources :threads do
      resources :posts
   end
end

#app/controllers/forum/threads_controller.rb
class Forum::ThreadsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @forum = Forum.find params[:id]
      @threads = @forum.threads
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working.

```
@forum_posts = @forum_thread.forum_posts.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
```